# Read only Textbox in Password

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a text box which get password from user and match from database then another form open.I want to make the textbox readonly when user user type his password and click button then the text box .text automatically gone to readonly property no one can copy the user password.
please give me solid solution
Thanks....

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: simply when you press the button, you clear the textbox. Readonly is incorrectly used here...readonly means you CANNOT modify an input.

Comment: why are you showing the password on textbox ? You can restrict the user to not copy paste but he can type hopefully..

Comment: yes ,I did that.Thanks

Comment: can any body tell me when  I create exe file of my application and I place my database file in it the error show that "YOU DON'T HAVE PERMISSION TO OPEN THIS FILE, CONTACT THE FILE OWNEROR AN ADMINISTRATOR TO OBTAIN PERMISSION "

Comment: Why are you placing your database file in exe? I don't see why you are doing that. Just put the address of your database server in connection string and your application will automatically connect with that database.

Comment: I place database in exe file because when a customer insert data or retrieve data it will get from the database file .I saw in tutorial  how to create exe file.

Comment: will you tell me how I automatically connect with the database

Answer (score 2):

set PasswordChar for TextBox after Button.Click

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = '*'
```

Comment: WILL YOU tell me when I create exe file of my application and I place my database file in it the error show that "YOU DON'T HAVE PERMISSION TO OPEN THIS FILE, CONTACT THE FILE OWNEROR AN ADMINISTRATOR TO OBTAIN PERMISSION "